cant recreate HIVE_FILESYSTEM_ERROR: Incorrect fileSize 1234567 for file
I'm trying to reproduce the following error in SQL Athena:

HIVE_FILESYSTEM_ERROR: Incorrect fileSize 1234567 for file

I've been tasked with recreating this error for testing purposes.
So far, I've attempted to:

Run a slow-running query selecting data from table T1.

Simultaneously    perform one of the following operations:

Deleting Parquet files from the table
. Duplicating Parquet files of
the table.
Replacing the contents of a Parquet file with different
data while keeping the same filename.



However, I haven't been able to reproduce the error.

athena vertion: 3.0
table size :~80k rows


The problem cannot be reproduced with just a slow running query, the files needs to be modified between phases of your query execution. When the query starts it's execution it will do the planning phase and this is when the initial count is recorded and same will be used for execution and between these two phases you need to perform the changes.
